# Access denied to create file after setting setfacl

Tags: ubuntu, acl

I have 2 accounts:

1. ubuntu - creates two directories /tmp/recursive and /tmp/recursive/subdir
2. user1 - tries to create file in /tmp/recursive and /tmp/recursive/subdir
   I set "setfacl -Rm d:u:user1:rwx /tmp/recursive" from ubuntu, but user1 still cannot create file. Please tell me where I'm wrong?

This is the result of "getfacl -R /tmp/recursive":

```
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:user1:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x

# file: tmp/recursive/example_file
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rw-
user:user1:rwx #effective:rw-
group::rwx #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::r—

# file: tmp/recursive/subdir
# owner: ubuntu
# group: ubuntu
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:user1:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the default option, your settings only apply to newly created files and folders.

To allow `user1` to write in "/tmp/recursive" you need to set the permission for already existing files as well:

```sh
setfacl -m u:user1:rwx /tmp/recursive
```

recursive:

```sh
setfacl -Rm u:user1:rwx /tmp/recursive
```